# Pass URL string to php without $_GET variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

On my local server (XAMPP) content of a file .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+?)(/.+)?$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

After uploading this file on server i can't pass parameters anymore. I got a message **"File not found."**

For example on local server i pass to url: *www.foo.com/admin*. And PHP variable $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] was equal to "admin"

Unfortunately on server this doesn't work. Can some explain why?

I do not want use this rule `#RewriteRule ^([^/.]+?)(/.+)?$ index.php?$1 [L]`. Because then i can't pass $_GET parameters. *www.foo.com/admin?id=1*

Comment: For the rule at the end of your question, you have to add the [QSA flag](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA).

Comment: @GrasDouble Thank you! You saved me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

It simply says match anything or everything entered after the `index.php/`

`[L]` tells the server to stop rewriting once it has applied that rule

I hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

(I won't comment about the `^([^/.]+?)(/.+)?$` part, but I guess it might be overcomplicated.)

So, you may try:

```
                                       ↓↓       ↓↓↓
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+?)(/.+)?$ index.php?/$1 [L, QSA]
```

- From my own experience too, you can omit the `?` on some servers, but it's much more compatible to add it.
- Then, you need the [QSA flag](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA) so the client's query string isn't dropped.
- You should not omit the slash, and use `?/$1`, so the application can better determine what part of the rewritten query string is about the URL prettification. For example, if you go to `example.org/controller?foobar`, the rewritten query string would be `?/controller&foobar`.